# What GUI libraries are not object-oriented?

Tags: user-interface, functional-programming, procedural-programming, imperative-programming

I have been using C a lot lately, and want to explore programming more than just console applications. However, most GUI libraries are object-oriented, and it is very difficult to program with them in programming languages which are not object-oriented such as C. Even object-oriented GUI libraries such as GTK+ that are designed for C require a lot of boilerplate. Because I am having difficulty with these object-oriented libraries I am wondering what GUI libraries are not object-oriented?

Comment: Wait, why don't you want to use some like Gtk, which is object-oriented C?

Comment: I don't understand @Marcin. I was specifically asking for a non object-oriented GUI library, and I wanted to challenge myself by programming that way.

Comment: What don't you understand? Why do you want to avoid using object-oriented libraries?

Comment: @Marcin I really don't undertand why your telling me to use Gtk. I thought it was pretty clear. I'm trying to write applications in a non object-oriented style for the challenge, and because it's fun.

Comment: I'm not telling you to use Gtk, I'm asking why you wouldn't want to use it.

Comment: both Tk and IUP are GUI toolkits that are non OOP for C

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any modern GUI toolkit that isn't object oriented.  OO is simply a very useful programming technique, even in C.

The only toolkit I can mention that I *think* is not OO is [Athena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xaw).  I haven't really used it, but did have one short CS lab assignment a long time ago that used Athena.

I suppose you could use [xlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xlib) directly, if you really want to avoid OO.

Comment: Thanks for commenting @dsh! Unfortunately, X programming really is a second class citizen on Mac OS X.

Comment: Indeed it is.  I think Cocoa is the only first-class GUI toolkit on OSX, but I'm not a Mac programmer.  Also, I think Cocoa is natively written in Objective C, which is an Object-Oriented derivative of C.  Not quite what you were asking for!