# How can I make a class that can inherit from any type of GTK+ 2.0 widget in C?

Tags: c, gtk, gobject

How can I make a class that can inherit from any type of GTK+ 2.0 widget in C? I know if I were to use C++ I would have a template that inherits from it's parameter and adds the behavior that I need, and that if I were to do something similar with Objective-C I might use NSProxy and forward messages to a class member which is the real view controller, but I have no idea how I'd accomplish the same task in C with GTK+ 2.0.

How can I make a class that can inherit from any type of GTK+ 2.0 widget in C?

P.S. Some are going to ask why. Asking why is fair enough. As you can see by my previous question [What GUI libraries are not object-oriented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013693/what-free-software-and-portable-gui-libraries-are-non-object-oriented) I have been challenging myself to program in a non object-oriented way. Because I want to program in a non object-oriented way, I need to abstract over all the classes available in GTK+ 2.0 to present the kind of behaviour I want. Specifically, I need to make each class work with continuations.

A simple continuation implementation is:

```
struct CONTINUATION;
typedef struct CONTINUATION continuation;
struct CONTINUATION {
     void* environment;
     continuation (*ip)(void*); 
};
```

A class which wants to send a message to it's continuation would continuously replace it's continuation with the results of it's ip applied to it's environment until the ip value points to the (stub) function event_get. Then, the class would use the information in environment to respond appropriately, and to get a new continuation, so the cycle can start all over again for the next message.

Comment: You want to be non object-oriented by passing messages to classes using inheritance? And to do that in C?!

Comment: @BoPersson I don't think that it's strange that I'd have to use object-oriented techniques to work with an object-oriented library. Why should it be any different because, I'm trying to build a non object-oriented layer on top. Besides, are templates, and proxies really pure oop? I don't think that the way I'll solve this in C will be pure oop either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy; whenever you want to inherit from a type use [`g_type_register_dynamic`](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Type-Information.html#g-type-register-dynamic) and supply the parent type.  I'm not clear why you'd want to subclass existing types, though; it'd seem easier in most cases to just attach your own information using [`g_object_set_qdata_full`](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set-qdata-full) and use existing signals to connect your continuations.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have decided to do this with C, the only option that you still have are macros, something like:

```
#define GtkStruct(x) \
struct x {   \
   int   base_class_field1;  \
   char *base_class_field2;
```

or

```
#define GtkStruct(x, base_type) \
struct x {   \
   base_type base_class_data;
```